# Cryptographically secure PRNG (PseudoRandom Number Generator)

Tags: java, algorithm, random, cryptography, prng

What is the best and fastest algorithm to generate cryptographically secure PRNG? My requirements is as follows.

- In each run, I need to generate few millions of numbers with length of 10.
- It should not allow one to predict future iterations by observing some number of iterations.
- Numbers should be unique. No duplicates allowed.
- Speed is also important since it will generate millions of numbers in each iteration.

I checked [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) algorithm but it seems it is not cryptographically secure. They said, it could be predicted by checking 624 iterations.

P.S. It would be better if there is a Java Implementation.

Comment: The one who put negative vote, please explain the reason.

Comment: Use Java's `SecureRandom`.  If that is not fast enough, then ask here again.

Comment: Pseudo-random number generators will always become predictable because they use deterministic methods to yield numbers. That's why they are *pseudo*-random. 

What you are apparently looking for is a [*real* random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudo-random_numbers). These typically use [hardware input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator), from mouse movements and video input to decaying radioactive material.

Comment: @rossum already checked SecureRandom but it is too slow and consumes too much CPU. I need a better option. I forgot to mention this in the question.

Comment: "Numbers should be unique". I can't think of _any_ random number generator, secure or not, that satisfies this. RNGs inevitably repeat.

Comment: Never roll your own RNG or Crypto. Use well-known, tested, mature code, and use it exactly as directed. The simplest, well-tested crypto PRNGs are the ones built into your OS: /dev/random on Linux, CryptGenRandom on Windows. The "no duplicates" thing is a problem with small numbers (10 digits). If you make them 150 digits (maybe even 100) you're pretty safe from duplicates. Otherwise you'll have to check manually. And of course...what are you actually trying to accomplish? I suspect you don't really need a CSPRNG at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your unique requirement means that you cannot use any sort of RNG (my earlier comment was wrong), since random numbers will include repeats.  Instead, use a cipher and encrypt the numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... which will give guaranteed unique results.  Since ciphers are reversible, each cyphertext decrypts back to the original plaintext, so the cyphertexts are a permutation of the plaintexts.

You also want numbers of "length ten".  I assume this means ten decimal digits, [1,000,000,000 .. 9,999,999,999].  That means you need a cipher which works in the range [0 .. 8,999,999,999], and just add 1e9 to the output.

That is more complex.  Either use the [Hasty Pudding cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_Pudding_cipher), which can be set for any range of numbers you want, or roll your own [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) with its block size set to the next higher power of 2.  If a number is out of range then re-encrypt it until it is in range.  The Feistel option will be faster, but less secure.  You can make it more secure by increasing the number of rounds at the cost of making it slower.

Comment: They keyword is [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) and I would recommend [AES-FFX](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ffx/ffx-spec.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

Use Linear feedback shift register. This algorithm is fast and secure.
Build register based on **primitive** characteristic polynomial of degree n. This will give the sequence of 2^n - 1 unique numbers. After that the sequence will repeat. Do not seed with zero. Some well-known stream cipher algorithms are based on LFSR, so you can extract and investigate implementation. For example LILI-128 (but its reference implementation in C)